# Powershell output difference when run in a loop

Tags: powershell

I have a command that runs fine from the CLI, and gives the output I want, e.g.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -server myserver group1 | select name | Sort-Object name

name
----
cervenka-1
habr-1
hoffmano-1
stepanek-1
urbanova-1
```

But, I now have lots of groups and would like to script the process. The issue is that when I try this same command inside a while loop:

```
$user = Get-ADGroupMember -server myserver $data[$a] | select name | Sort-Object name
```

It gives this as output:

```
@{name=cervenka-1}
@{name=habr-1}
@{name=hoffmano-1}
@{name=stepanek-1}
@{name=urbanova-1}
```

As I just want the names, and nothing else, should I parse the output to remove the unwanted chars or is there a way of getting the same output as the CLI command directly?

Comment: use select-object -expandproperty name in the loop

Comment: "-expandproperty" fixed it - many thanks!